# Generate and "unconverted" binary string based on dictionary references

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, binary

```
random_pool=[[[0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 0, 1], [0, 1], [1], [0]],
 [[0, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1], [0, 3], [3], [1]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0], [2, 2], [4], [2]],
 [[2, 1, 3, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0], [2, 1], [3], [3]]]


def BinaryConversion(random_pool):
    global binary_list
    binary_list = []
    binary_index = {0: (0,0), 1: (0,1), 2: (1,0), 3: (1,1)}    
    for game in range (0, len(random_pool)):
        converted = [s for num in random_pool[game][0] for s in binary_index[num]]    
        binary_list.append(converted)    
    return (binary_list)

def GeneratePopulation(random_pool, binary_list):   
    global population
    individual = []    
    population = []  
    for ind in range (0, len(binary_list)):
        individual = [binary_list[ind],random_pool[ind][2],random_pool[ind][3]] 
        population.append(individual)    
    return (population)

def BinaryReturn(population):
    binary_return_l=[]
    binary_return_index = {(0,0): 0, (0,1): 1, (1,0): 2, (1,1): 3} 
    for game in range (0, len(population)):
        returned = [s for num in population[game][0] for s in binary_return_index[num]]
        binary_return_l.append(returned)
    return(bynary_return_l)

binary =  BinaryConversion(random_pool)
print ("\n")
print ("\n",binary_list)

pop = GeneratePopulation(random_pool, binary_list)
print ("\n")
print ("\n",population)

unconverted = BinaryReturn(population)
print ("\n")
print ("\n",bynary_return_l)
```

Hello everyone, I have this code above to perform the following operations, 1 - convert an integer vector into binary based on a dictionary reference (working fine), 2 - generate a "population" appending items from another list (which I believe its not important here), and 3 - unconvert the binary strings back to numbers based on the same logic.

The problem is on the third part, `BinaryReturn(population)`. I am trying to perform the inverse operation from the binary conversion code, but It is not working, I get the message `KeyError: 0`. Anyone know what could I be doing wrong here?

Thank you!

Comment: You are trying to use the key `0` on your dictionary, but it doesn't have that key...

Comment: So the problem would be in the key definition `(0,0): 0` or that it is defined wrongly?

Comment: I don't understand your question. But your dictionary lacks a `0` key.

Comment: I think the problem is the program is taking separate values instead of pairs, that is why there is no `0` alone, but `0,0 and 0,1`